# How to properly count an actual number of forked child processes?

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, waitpid

Some time ago I wrote a simple SMTP gate for automatic S/MIME processing and now it comes to testing. As typical for mail servers, **main process forks a child for every incoming connection**. It is a good practice to limit the number of created child processes -- and so I done it.

During heavy load (many connections from many clients at the same time) it appears that **child processes are not correctly counted** -- the problem is in decreasing the counter when children exits. After a few minutes of heavy load counter is greater than actual number of child processes (ie. after 5 minutes it equals 14, but there are none).

I already did some research, but nothing worked. All zombie processes are reaped, so `SIGCHLD` handling seem to be ok. I thought that it may be a synchronization problem, but adding a mutex and changing variable type to `volatile sig_atomic_t` (as it is now) gives no change. It is also not a problem with signal masking, I tried masking all signal using `sigfillset(&act.sa_mask)`.

I noticed that `waitpid()` sometimes returns strange PID values (very large, like 172915914).

**Questions and some code.**

1. Is it possible that other process (ie. `init`) is reaping some of them?
2. Can a process not become a zombie after exit? Can it be reaped automatically?
3. How to fix it? Maybe there is a better way of counting them?

Forking a child in `main()`:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sproc_counter = 0;    /* forked subprocesses counter */

/* S/MIME Gate main function */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    [...]

    /* set appropriate handler for SIGCHLD */
    Signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);

    [...]

    /* SMTP Server's main loop */
    for (;;) {

        [...]

        /* check whether subprocesses limit is not exceeded  */
        if (sproc_counter < MAXSUBPROC) {
            if ( (childpid = Fork()) == 0) {    /* child process */
                Close(listenfd);                /* close listening socket */
                smime_gate_service(connfd);     /* process the request */
                exit(0);
            }
            ++sproc_counter;
        }
        else
            err_msg("subprocesses limit exceeded, connection refused");

        [...]
    }
    Close(connfd);  /* parent closes connected socket */
}
```

Signal handling:

```
Sigfunc *signal (int signo, Sigfunc *func)
{
    struct sigaction    act, oact;

    act.sa_handler = func;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (signo == SIGALRM) {
#ifdef  SA_INTERRUPT
        act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;   /* SunOS 4.x */
#endif
    }
    else {
#ifdef  SA_RESTART
        act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;     /* SVR4, 44BSD */
#endif
    }
    if (sigaction(signo, &act, &oact) < 0)
        return SIG_ERR;

    return oact.sa_handler;
}

Sigfunc *Signal (int signo, Sigfunc *func)
{
    Sigfunc *sigfunc;

    if ( (sigfunc = signal(signo, func)) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal error");
    return sigfunc;
}

void sig_chld (int signo __attribute__((__unused__)))
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;

    while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        --sproc_counter;
        err_msg("child %d terminated", pid);
    }
    return;
}
```

**NOTE**: All functions beginning with a capital letter (like `Fork()`, `Close()`, `Signal()` etc.) do and behaves the same as they lower case friends (`fork()`, `close()`, `signal()` etc.), but have better error handling -- so I don't have to check their return statuses.

**NOTE2**: I run and compile it under Debian Testing (`kernel v3.10.11`) using `gcc 4.8.2`.

Comment: Consider making your code call sig_chld() periodically, for example in a thread. Rather than in a signal handler function.  Signal handlers like yours have the potential  not to complete correctly when there is a barrage of signals. Which it seems is your problem.

Comment: What does your `Fork` function do when `fork` fails?

Comment: It prints an error message and exits calling `exit(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the signal method can be fixed, while creating a thread forces you to exec a program to handle a connection.

There are several problems:

- Changes to `sproc_counter` may be lost if a process is created and ended at the same time. To fix this, either use signal masks (e.g., `sigprocmask()`, `pselect()`) to ensure the handler is not invoked while the main flow is manipulating `sproc_counter`, or make the signal handler set a flag and perform the `waitpid()`, counter manipulation and logging in the main flow (but not in a new thread). Note that the flag method still requires signal mask manipulation if you want to avoid sleeping for a new connection or another ending connection directly after an ending connection.
- `err_msg()` is probably not async-signal safe. I see three options:

  - use the flag method mentioned above, or
  - ensure no async-signal unsafe functions are called while `SIGCHLD` is unmasked, or
  - remove the call from the signal handler.
- Overriding `signal()` may cause other code to invoke your version instead of the standard version. This is likely to lead to strange behaviour.
- The signal handler does not save and restore the value of `errno`.

If you have problems because of signals interrupting other signals, that's what `sigaction`'s `sa_mask` field is for.

Comment: Yeah, the way with manipulating signal mask works well! And is much simpler. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself.

**There are several reasons for not to count child processes this way**. Firstly signal handler could be interrupted by another signal. I can't find any information, what actually happens when this situation occurs. There are some info about it on libc manual pages and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345065/3157524). But that may not be an issue.

It seems that **operations on `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable are not really atomic** and it depend on system architecture. In example, on *amd64* compiled code of decrementing `sproc_counter` value looks like that:

```
movl    sproc_counter(%rip), %eax
subl    $1, %eax
movl    %eax, sproc_counter(%rip)
```

As you can see, there are as much as three assembler instructions! It's definitely not atomic, so access to `sproc_counter` have to be synchronized.

Okay, but why adding a mutex did not give a result? Answer is on manual page of `pthread_mutex_lock()`/`pthread_mutex_unlock()`:

> **ASYNC-SIGNAL SAFETY**
>
> The  mutex functions are not async-signal safe. What this means is that
>   **they should not be called from a signal handler**. In particular, calling
>   pthread_mutex_lock  or  pthread_mutex_unlock  from a signal handler may
>   deadlock the calling thread.

That makes it clear. What is more calling functions, which print date (log message) is also a bad idea -- used there `fputs()` is not async-signal-safe.

**How to do it correctly?**

Having in mind what can happen during signal handling (ie. delivery of other signals), it quite clear that signal handling routine should be as terse as possible. **It is much better to [set a flag in handler](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Usage.html#Atomic-Usage) and test it from time to time in the main program or dedicated thread**. I choose the second solution.

No more words, let's see some code.

Signal handling will look that way:

```
void sig_chld (int signo __attribute__((__unused__)))
{
  sigchld_notify = 1;
}
```

The `main()` routine:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sigchld_notify = 0;                /* SIGCHLD notifier */
int sproc_counter = 0;                                   /* forked child process counter */
pthread_mutex_t sproc_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; /* mutex for child process counter */

/* S/MIME Gate main function */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t guard_id;
    [...]

    /* start child process guard */
    if (0 != pthread_create(&guard_id, NULL, child_process_guard, NULL) )
        err_sys("pthread_create error");

    [...]

    /* SMTP Server's main loop */
    for (;;) {
        [...]

        /* check whether child processes limit is not exceeded */
        if (sproc_counter < MAXSUBPROC) {
            if ( (childpid = Fork()) == 0) { /* child process */
                Close(listenfd);             /* close listening socket */
                smime_gate_service(connfd);  /* process the request */
                exit(0);
            }
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sproc_mutex);
            ++sproc_counter;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sproc_mutex);
        }
        else
            err_msg("subprocesses limit exceeded, connection refused");

        Close(connfd); /* parent closes connected socket */
    }
} /* end of main() */
```

Guarding thread routine:

```
extern volatile sig_atomic_t sigchld_notify; /* SIGCHLD notifier */
extern int sproc_counter;                    /* forked child process counter */
extern pthread_mutex_t sproc_mutex;          /* mutex for child process counter */

void* child_process_guard (void* arg __attribute__((__unused__)))
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;

    for (;;) {
        if (0 == sigchld_notify) {
            usleep(SIGCHLD_SLEEP);
            continue;
        }

        while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sproc_mutex);
            --sproc_counter;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sproc_mutex);
            err_msg("child %d terminated", pid);
        }
        sigchld_notify = 0;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Note that `smime_gate_service()` may only use async-signal safe functions such as `execve()` if you do it this way. This is because `fork()` replicates only the calling thread in the new process, while other threads may own locks (including locks used internally by the system).

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I did not come to think of how forking and threads interfere. But this is rather not an issue -- `smime_gate_service()` is a single-threaded, do not perform forks and don't have any signal handling. There are no more threads and forks than you see in this code excerpt. It's even better that only the main thread is replicated -- because that's the only one I need.

Comment: There can still be a problem, for example if a fork happens while the child process guard thread is in `err_msg()`, and the child process also uses `err_msg()` later. The data structures may be inconsistent, or you may be waiting for a thread that does not exist in the child process to unlock something (in particular, stdio `FILE` objects are specified to be locked).

Comment: Ah now I see, but that's kind of frightening vision -- and worse, it's real! Do you think enlarging critical sections is enough? (in `main()` to have `fork()` inside; in `child_process_guard()` to have `err_msg()` inside) Is `waitpid()` and `usleep()` safe for multithread forking?